# Converting a string in a dictionary into tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have this dictionary and I would like to convert the values to a tuple with 3 integers(day, month, year).

`my_dict = {"date": "1.1.2020"]`

I'll be glad for some guidance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I meant (1, 1, 2020)

Comment: Thats what you want. He means what data do you have as input? Because what you are showing is not a valid Python data structure.

Comment: @Guerrero That would be your expected tuple value, not your input - I was asking about the latter

Answer (score 7):

You can use `map` function

```
tuple(map(int,'1.1.2020'.split('.')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `dict` with string values:

```
my_dict = {"date": "1.1.2020"}
```

you can do the following:

```
my_dict = {k: tuple(int(x) for x in v.split(".")) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
 # Or
# my_dict = {k: tuple(map(int, v.split("."))) for k, v in my_dict.items()}

{'date': (1, 1, 2020)}
```